# Why does this debounce function not work?

Tags: python, button, debouncing

So I'm trying to make a simple debounce and I just can't figure out where I messed up.
Here is the code:

```
def debounce(var, db):
    if var == 1 and db == 0:
        db = 1
    elif var == 0:
        db = 0
    else:
        var = 0
    return var, db


while True:
    mouse_buttons = get_mouse_buttons()    # -This is the fuction that if the mouse's buttons are pressed

    pressed, db = debounce(mouse_buttons[0], db)
    mouse_buttons = (pressed, 0, 0)

    print(mouse_buttons[0])
```

My expected output would be if I press the mouse button, then it would be a 1 for once, then turn 0 untill I release and press it again. The current code gives out a 1 for the first time, and no matter what, it only gives out 0 after. (I tested it, it has nothing to do with the function that returns the pressed buttons on the mouse.)

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more of the expected result of the function, and what does not work properly (unexpected return? Error?) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I edited it it be more precise.

Comment: what value does db start with - just form completeness ?

Comment: Actually it works for me when replacing the function `get_mouse_buttons()` by `def get_mouse_buttons():
    return [int(input())]` to simulate a click with an input.

Comment: @HemChab - that suggest therefore that `get_mouse_buttons()` isn't doing what is expected.

Comment: Yop, definitely, the debounce function should not be in cause there

Comment: @HenriChab - I concur. I just repeated the test with `get_mouse_buttons()` replaced with `(int(input('>>').lower()=='y'), 0, 0)`. Where a input of 'y' or 'Y' is the button being pressed, and I get the expected results - the code only prints 1 when you go from 'n' to 'y' which is the intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm your test expectations

```
var  |  db  |  var,db 
----------------------
  0     0      0,0
  0     1      0,0
  1     0      1,1
  1     1      0,1
```

If this is correct then I am not sure that your function does do that.

This is simpler - to reproduce the same logic table.

```
def debounce(var, db):
    return var and not db, var
```

In this case when var is 0 - this will return 0,0
When var is 1 this will return 1,1 if db == 0
When var is 0 this will return 0,1 if db == 1

Addendum - when I re-ran your code with `get_mouse_buttons()` replaced with this :

```
def get_mouse_buttons():
    return (int(input('>>').lower()=='y'), 0, 0)
```

Where you get to decide (by typing Y/y) whether the mouse button is pressed, it turns out that your debounce code - although clunky does actually do what is expected - your loop only prints a 1 when you type a 'y' initially or you go from not a 'y' to a 'y' - ie your code correctly detects the initial change from non-pressed to pressed.

Since you state your code doesn't work thereofre th clear suspect is your get_mouse_buttons() function - which you have claimed works ok.

Comment: Very clear to make it a logic table but I think it does produce that: if `var=0`, then it goes through the second condition so var stays at 0 and db is set to 0, so it returns `(0, 0)`. If `var=1` and `db=0`, we are in the first condition and it returns `(1, 1)` as db becomes 0. Finally, if `var=1` and `db=1`, we are in the third condition and it returns `(0, 1)` as var is set to 0. am I missing something? It should give the right result.

Comment: @HenriChab - maybe I parsed the multiple ifs wrong then - I prefer the logic rather than nested ands.

Comment: Your solution is definitely better! But I try to understand why his solution does not work

Comment: @HenriChab as you suggest - it does work when you use `input` so that suggest (as I mentioned in the other comment chain) that `get_mouse_buttons()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

debounce always needs to set `db`.  You don't do that in all cases.  If you want `pressed` to be the debounced value, then you want:

```
def debounce(var, db):
    if var == 1 and db == 0:
        db = 1
    else:
        db = 0
    return db, var
```

To figure this out, write the states down on paper over time:

```
var = 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 db = 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: the problem is, that when db is already 1, he wants to return var as 0 - ie ignore continued button presses.

Comment: He wants the first parameter to return 0 in that case.  This does that.  Notice that I swapped the order of the return values.  The `db` in his main program need to be the memory of what the actual button press was last time.  That comes in the `debounce` as `var`.

Comment: you are right - I hadn't spotted that you had swapped the values of db and var.